# AddEventListener not working when trying to excute my HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, addeventlistener

I am trying to make this work (JavaScript file linked with my HTML and CSS)  but for some reason it does not work. Any suggestions?

I do not understand whether the error is in my JavaScript or if it is due to how I typed in my HTML.

Just to be sure, I have enclosed my CSS code as well; It might be possible that there is some mistake as well.

script.js:

```js
//targets

let snake = document.getElementById("snake");
let space = document.getElementById("space");
let fortune = document.getElementById("fortune");

//elements to be changed

let figure1 = document.getElementById("figure1");
let figure2 = document.getElementById("figure3");
let figure3 = document.getElementById("figure3");

//functions

snake.addEventListener("click",function(){
    figure1.style.display = "";
});

space.addEventListener("click",function(){
    figure2.style.display = "";
});

fortune.addEventListener("click",function(){
    figure3.style.display = "";
});
```

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
    <script src="./script.js"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=MuseoModerno:ital,wght@0,500;0,700;1,300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>My portfolio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <h1>Simone</h1>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About me</a></li>
                <li><a href="#face">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="./contact.html" target="_blank">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <article>
            <h2>About me</h2>
            <img id="face" src="./face.jpg" alt="Simone's face">
            <p class="about">Ciao! my name is Simone, a self-taught front-end web developer based in England. 
                I am 26 years old and currently looking for my first job in the tech industry.</p>
            <p class="about">I have got one year of experience in executing front-end mobile and web developement using Python,
                HTML5, JavaScript and CSS3.</p>
            <p class="about">I am committed to creating high presentation UI with exceptional handling to enhance user experience.</p>
            <p class="about">In my spare time I enjoy travelling and going to the gym.</p>
        </article>
        <section class="projects">
            <h2>Projects</h2>
            <ul>
                <li id="snake" class="project">Snake Game with Python</li>
                    <figure id="figure1"><img src="./snake.png" alt="Snake Game"><figcaption>Snake game developed using pygame.</figcaption></figure>
                <li id="space" class="project">Space battleship</li>
                    <figure id="figure2"><img id="ship" src="./spaceship.png" alt="Spaceship"><figcaption id="figship">Spaceship game developed using pygame.</figcaption></figure>
                <li id="fortune" class="project">JavaScript Fortune teller</li>
                    <figure id="figure3"><img src="./fortune.png" alt="JavaScript"><figcaption>Fortune teller generator using JavaScript</figcaption></figure>
            </ul>
.....
```

CSS:

```css
html {
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: 'Museo Moderno',cursive;
    background-color: hsla(0,70%,95%);
}

a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    font-weight: bold;
}

a:hover{
    color: brown;
}


h1{
    margin-top: 5rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

header nav{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: flex-end;
    justify-content: flex-end;
    
}

header nav ul{
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    margin-top: -3.8rem;
    
    
    
}

header nav ul li{
    margin: 0.5rem 3rem 0.5rem 3rem;
    list-style: none;
    
}

h2{
    margin-left: 2rem;
    margin-top:1rem;
}

main article{
    display: block;
}

main article .about{
    margin-left: 4rem;
    margin-top: 1.5rem;
}

#face{
    float: inline-end;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    margin-right: 2rem;
    margin-right: 2.7rem;
}

main .projects{
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    margin-top: 2rem;
}

main .projects ul {
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-left: 2rem;
}

#figure1{
    display: none;
}

#figure2{
    display: none;
}

#figure3{
    display: none;
}

#ship{
    width: 10rem;
    margin-left: -4rem;
}

#figship{
    margin-left: -4rem;
}
main .projects .project {
    margin-top: 1rem;
}

#skills{
    display: block;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}
main .skills{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:space-between;
    margin-left: 3rem;
    margin-right: 3rem;
}

main .skills img{
    width: 10rem;
    
}

hr{
    margin-top: 2rem;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

main footer .bottom{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: Maybe adding the defer attribute to your script does the "trick". https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script#attr-defer

Comment: Just add your script file in the end of the body

Answer (score 0):

You are addding your js before the element is created, as @ericmp said, one option is to add the defer attribute to your script element, another option is to add you script element somewhere after the element, like at the end of your body tag.

Comment: This is a [very common duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/14028959?lq=1). From [answer]: "_avoid trying to answer questions which... ...have already been asked and answered many times before._"

Comment: @Ivar By the way, the document getElementById is working

Comment: @ThomasZimmermann No it isn't. It is working in your answer because Stack Snippets append the script part of the snippet at the end of the HTML, but in OP's example they have script in their `<head>` tag on the 8th line. It is being executed before the elements exist in the DOM.

Comment: @Ivar Always happy to be wrong, I learnt something